# pycharm doesn't recognize python functions

Tags: pycharm

I just updated to pycharm 2.6 and since the update pycharm doesn't recognize the default python functions anymore. With default functions I mean the super() str() etc. functions.

Does anybody know how to fix this? I already tried removing and re-adding the interpreter and stuff but nothing seems to do the trick. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug, please [track the progress here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7451).

**UPDATE**: Fixed in [PyCharm 2.6.1+](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/index.html).

Comment: The bug seems to exist in Pycharm 3.0.2 (Community). I have to manually add popular built-ins to the ignore list

Comment: FWIW I had the problem with 3.4 and a virtualenv.  Was due (i think) to duplicate paths (/python3.4 and plat-darwin, for me).  Go to project properties => interpreters => gear icon => more => <your venv> => show path => remove the duplicates (they prob. point outside your virtualenv's root).  After that I closed the dialog, reopened the "interpreter paths" dialog, and hit refresh at the bottom.  Works now.