# Pycharm : Showing error in dict keyword?

Tags: python, syntax, error-handling, syntax-error, pycharm

I am using `Pycharm` : `2.6`

Problem is its error checking is behaving very weird. I have a piece of code that is working as expected. But pycharm is showing error in basic constructs of `python`

Am I doing something wrong ?

Or

Can I make it show error on `keyword` `dict` ?

**Here is a screenshot :**

[image: error in keyword dict]

Error : `Unresolved reference dict` [ How is that possible ]

How can I fix it ? I am not able to work with this kind of errors !

Comment: Is PyCharm's interpreter config set up correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [pycharm doesn't recognize python functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280109/pycharm-doesnt-recognize-python-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is documented in [PY-7451](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-7451). It has been fixed in PyCharm 2.6.1.

Comment: Are involved in Pycharm development ?

Comment: Yes, I'm a developer of PyCharm.

Comment: First off - Thanks for such a great IDE.

`Is it possible to have real-time pylint checking with pycharm ?` 
Can you share a link / post describing how to do it ?
I know the code inspection does a similar job.

Comment: We are working hard at making our on-the-fly code inspections do the job of code analysis tools such as pylint. If you find any false warnings our inspections produce or any code you should have been warned about, please let us know by submitting an issue to our issue tracker. If you really need to use the pylint tool, you can set up an external tool configuration for it (Settings -> External Tools).

Comment: I see a lot of false warnings. The most frequent is `Unresolved library` for `{% load my_custom_tags %}`. It runs as expected that too when I run the server via pycharm. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please send your bug reports to our [issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY). Does this bug appear only for Django templates? Please provide a small reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: Sure.. I will try to have a reproducible example and file a bug on your `issue tracker`. I tried external tools for Pylint, it was not helpful as an external tool. I desire if that could auto-correct the spaces, etc in my code in the real-time that pycharm doesn't do as of now.

Comment: I suppose text-editors [ non IDE ] offer realtime pylinting, pep8 stuff. `Sublime` and `TextMate` I suppose. So, is there a blocking for such a good IDE to have a life-saver feature ?

Comment: PEP-8: PyCharm offers the Reformat Code Block feature that automatically formats your code according your code style settings. PyLint: Our inspections do similar checks and show less false positive warnings. Please see my comment above.

Comment: No, it is not - i'm running version 3.0.2 (community)

Answer (score 0):

You may have encountered this bug: [PyCharm doesn't recognize builtins for me](http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-291)

The recommended solution was:

> The "Reload" button in Settings | Python Interpreters regenerates the
>   skeletons for binary modules, including builtins. Please try pressing
>   it.

Comment: They say that its fixed in `2.6.1` I was not able to find the `reload` button.